# Orphaned files after a delete on the network

Tags: c#, .net, io

We have been having an issue for over a year that we have yet to resolve. We have a custom deployment type tools that essentially copies files from a staging area to our live production server that live on two different network shares. Out app is conceptually simple.

One of the first thing we do before we copy a file to see if that file exist on the destination (and it usually does) and rename the file. If the file is called 'myfile.dll' we rename it to 'myfile.dll.bak'. We do this to try to get around file locking problems in windows (sometimes you can still copy a file even if its locked if you rename it). So essentially all we are doing is:

```
File.SetAttributes(destFileName, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Move(destFileName, destFileName + ".bak");
```

At the end of the process we delete all the .bak files:

```
Directory.GetFiles(msCopyTo, "*.bak").ToList().ForEach(currFile =>
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Deleting file {0}, ....", currFile));
    File.SetAttributes(currFile, FileAttributes.Normal);
    //strips off the read only bit if there is one
    File.Delete(currFile);
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Deleted File {0}", currFile));
})
```

We run this process daily and mostly it works. Occasionally though it doesn't. The process won't fail though so, to .Net, it looks like the `.delete()` was successful. It will leave a orphaned file .bak file. What do i mean by orphaned. Well the file will have absolutely no security on it. Even people who have full access to that directory can't delete/read or take ownership of the file. When you reboot the file server the file will be gone.

We sent this issue to our network admins and they have pretty much gave up. They said people rename/delete files daily and the only problem they have seen is the files copied with this process.

This causes problems for processes looking at this directory because they will get a "Read Denied" error when trying to read one of these orphaned files and its kind of hard to reboot a highly used file server to clear out these problems. We just replaced the hardware on the file server with a fresh copy of Server 2012 R2 and its still happening :(

Some hardare info:
Clients: Usually Win 7 x64
Server: Server 2012 R2
        drives are attached SAN drivers (xiotech SAN)

Comment: Are you able to get a consistent repro? I would wrap a try catch around it and log it somewhere. Because you currently have no idea. More error information/diagnostic would help.

Comment: Nope. 99.99% of the time it works without an issue. We run this process every day (sometimes multiple times) and it happens maybe once every couple months.

Comment: There is try/catches around almost everything and as soon as an error happens we immediately bubble up the errors to the client. When this issue happens, we have yet to see the process fail

Comment: There are too many scenarios, I'm assuming this is being run over the network, are there any network drops or packet loss? I don't think we can help answer this question. Run the program on the local machine or rewrite your code